# Include error : sqlfront.h & sqldb.h

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Why do i get an error when I try to include **sqlfront.h** & **sqldb.h** in my program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this line to your code

```
    #define DBNTWIN32
```

to tell SQL Server if it is WINT or Win95.

Like this:

```
 #define DBNTWIN32 
 #include <windows.h> 
 #include <sqlfront.h> 
 #include <sqldb.h>
```

Comment: Even after Adding this line , it will show the same error i.e., directory not exists.

Comment: Which version of visual Studio are using in your system?

Comment: using Visual studio 2008 to connect ms-sql2005 .